# Javascript Promise.all() not resolving or rejecting

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Given the following code:

```
                let promiseArray = [];
fs.readdir('someFolderHere', (err, fileList) => {
                filesList.forEach(filename => {
                    // readFile returns a promise that resolves 
                    // to an array of strings to insert into the database
                    readFile(fileName).then((records) => { 
                        records.forEach((record) => {
                            promiseArray.push(db.insert(record)); // db.insert returns a promise
                        });
                    });
                });

                // console.log(promiseArray); // empty array here??? 
    
                Promise.all(promiseArray).then((res) => {
                    console.log('resolved');
                    resolve(res);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log('rejected');
                    reject(err);
                });
    });
```

I cannot figure out why the promiseArray isn't resolving in the Promise.all(). Neither of those console.log statements print out.

At a guess, I would suppose that the Promise.all is called before the promiseArray is populated, so that it is a blank array, e.g. **Promise.all([ ]).then(...)**

How do I get around this. I am trying to read a list of files, for each file, I am reading several lines of data. I need all records from all files to be inserted into the database - promises just are not playing nice. Is there any way to make the Promise.all wait until promiseArray has been fully populated and the forEach is fully completed?

Comment: `Promise.all(promiseArray)` is called before any of `promiseArray.push(db.insert(record)); ` is executed

Comment: @DraganS Yes, I suspected as much... How do I get around it?

Comment: It depends on the requirements. How will you handle an error. Will you update db or db will be updated only if all files have managed to load records.

Comment: use `for (const p of promises) ..... ` => this makes one wait for the next ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you stop using `then`, your code will automagically get shorter and cleaner. Example:

```js
let readFile = path => [path + ' record1', path + ' record2']
let insert = record => 'insert ' + record

async function test(fileList) {
    let records = await Promise.all(fileList.map(path => readFile(path)))
    return Promise.all(records.flat().map(rec => insert(rec)))
}

test(['A', 'B', 'C']).then(console.log);
```

These two lines do the same as your 10+ lines function.

In response to your comment, you can apply the same generic pattern when working with "exploding" maps, where each element maps to an array (like folders -> files in each folder, files -> records in each file etc).

```
let folders = await Promise.all(serverList.map(server => getFolderOn(server)))
let files = await Promise.all(folders.flat().map(folder => getFilesIn(folder)))
let records = await Promise.all(files.flat().map(file => getRecordsIn(file)))

and so on...
```

You can save a bit of typing, and define a generic function like

```
let flatPromise = (arrayOfArrays, mapper) =>
    Promise.all(arrayOfArrays.flat().map(mapper))
```

and then

```
let folders = await flatPromise(serverList, server => getFolderOn(server))
let files = await flatPromise(folders, folder => getFilesIn(folder))
let records = await flatPromise(files, file => getRecordsIn(file))
....
```

Comment: You should use `.map(f => readFile(f))` because `.map` will pass unintended arguments to `readFile`

Comment: This should be a correct answer. Not sure whether flatMap can be replaced with the map method here.
```
 async function a ()  {
   const filesList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
   let records = await Promise.all(filesList.map((file) => Promise.resolve([file, file])))
   return Promise.all(records.map(rec => Promise.resolve(rec)))
}

a().then(x => console.log(x));
``

Comment: @DraganS: right, it should be `flat().map`. Updated.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate this - I've now had to iterate over a folder too, which is yet another promise surrounding the code. Is it possible to include that into your test function too?

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is exactly right — you're calling `Promise.all` with an empty array, because your code for adding to the array is in a fulfillment callback that hasn't happened yet.

Instead, it would probably be something like this (see comments):

```
// Map the file list to an array of promises that will be fulfilled
// with an array of promises for the records.
const promiseArray = Promise.all(
    // For each entry in `filesList`...
    filesList.map(
        // ...read the file and then...
        filename => readFile(filename).then(
            // ...take its records and insert them...
            records => Promise.all(
                records.map(
                    record => db.insert(record)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
.then((res) => {
    console.log('resolved');
    resolve(res); // This is suspect, see below
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('rejected');
    reject(err);  // This is suspect, see below
});
```

The `resolve` and `reject` calls are suspect, they make me think the code is fallilng into the explicit promise creation anti-pattern. You *already* have a promise (from `Promise.all`), so you can just return it instead of returning a promise created via `new Promise`.

**However**, unless this is all in some kind of transaction, you might want to use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) rather than `Promise.all` so you have a view of what did and didn't succeed, in case reading some files fails but others works.